# How to check if excel file is blank?

Tags: java, excel

I have excel file (`*.xls` or `*.xlxs`) which can have records or no records. First I store the file in some temp location, then copy the contents of the file and then tried to read the file. This scenario works fine if the excel sheet contains records but if the sheet has no record and the file is empty. This scenario does not work. I am using apache-poi to read the excel file contents.

```
public static boolean isRowEmpty(Row row) {
    for (int c = row.getFirstCellNum(); c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
        if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get `IOException : unable to read entire header 0 bytes read expected 512 bytes`. Can somebody suggest me a way to get rid of this exception and check the excel file is empty?

Comment: If the file is really empty (0 byte), it is not a valid XLS file. So you should check the size of the file prior to opening it with apache-poi. See File.length method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length().

Comment: @Xvolks The file exists so File.length() will return a value, it will not be 0L so this check is not applicable.

Comment: @Harleen, please check out my answer

Comment: btw, philosophical question: Does existence of non-default sheets make file not empty? The same question about other meta structures. So it's up to developer dicide what is emptiness of such complex data formats as `xls` or `BD`, but we have first to create definition of emptiness for every particular case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling and some experiments with `org.apache.poi` library suggest to me that it is abnormal to check if `xls` file is empty without knowing even approximately the data structure within it. It's as hard as to say if, for example, `Oracle BD` is empty. 
Any way, you are able to fetch quantity of sheets then iterate over all of them, check rows and cells and consider file is empty if you found nothing.

```
HSSFWorkbook wBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("your_path"));  
for(int i = 0; i < wBook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++){
       System.out.println("Sheet " + i + " has data: " + isSheetEmpty(wBook.getSheetAt(i)));
}
boolean isSheetEmpty(HSSFSheet sheet){
       Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
       while (rows.hasNext()) {
           HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
           Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
           while (cells.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                if(!cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()){
                    return true;
                }
           }
       }
       return false;
}
```

Comment: I made few edits after testing this code. it works fine now

Comment: My problem is solved now. Actually the workbook object was set as null when I was doing                                                            HSSFWorkbook wBook = new HSSFWorkbook(inStream);                                                                      but with your piece of code:                                            HSSFWorkbook wBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("your_path")); It is creating workbook object. Now the IOException is not coming.     Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Using Apache Poi (org.apache.poi) for the solution and skipping the parts where I actually get the Workbook (excel) and get access to it's sheets.

If you want to know if sheet is empty use this, modify the solution to loop through sheets to find out if all of the sheets in the file are empty.

```
    if (sheet.getLastRowNum() == 0 && sheet.getRow(0) == null) {
        // This is the case when the sheet is empty!
    }
```

getLastRowNum() - returns 0 in case of empty sheet or if there is only data in the first row

getRow(0) - returns null if there is no data in the row

NOTE: the solution doesn't take empty strings, spaces, empty lines and etc. into account

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
private boolean isSheetEmpty(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    Row row = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        row = (Row) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            cell = (Cell) cells.next();
            if (!cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (cell  == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    return true;
 }
return false;
```

Try this one !

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.

Comment: Add some explanation, don't put code out of the blue without any context of explanations